# Dynamic height UITextView inside scrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm working on a detail view for my app that lets people discover movies. I set up my detail view in interface builder by first adding a contentView to which I added my other views. I understand from previous topics that the contentView should dictate the contentSize of the scrollView. I also understand that the views inside the contentView should have auto layout constraints that enable the contentView to calculate its full size (in my case the height). I haven't been able to get this to work perfectly. I suspect that this is because I have a textview that displays the movie description and because some of these are long and some are short I don't know how to set its size. I want the textView to display the full text and I want to disable scrolling. In the current situation when the text is long the labels or the buttons get compressed. When I add height constraints to the labels and other views the textview gets compressed. Could anyone guide me in the correct direction/ let me know what I'm doing wrong?

This is how I set up the view hierarchy:

- UIScrollView
- - UIView (trailing, leading, top & bottom = 0, centerY & centerX)
- - - UIImageView (trailing, leading, top to contentView = 0, aspectRatio)
- - - UILabel (centerX, top to ImageView & bottom to label = standard)
- - - UILabel (centerX, top to label & bottom to label = standard)
- - - UILabel (centerX, top to label & bottom to label = standard)
- - - UILabel (centerX, top to label & bottom to textView = standard)
- - - UITextView (leading, trailing & bottom horizontalScroller = standard)
- - - HorizontalImageScroller (leading, trailing & bottom to UIButtons = standard , Height of contentView == height of scroller to disable vertical scrolling)
- - - UIButton (leading, bottom to contentView = standard)
- - - UIButton (leading, bottom to contentView = standard)

**Solution:**

Instead of a textView I used a UILabel with number of lines set to 0 and line breaks set to word wrap. After that I still didn't get the results that I was looking for. Then I had to change some auto layout constraints after which it finally worked.

The following articles where helpful to me while solving this issue:

[Article about content sizing priorities](http://krakendev.io/blog/autolayout-magic-like-harry-potter-but-real)

[Article about Debugging AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/DebuggingTricksAndTips.html)

Comment: If you don't want scrolling why not use a UILabel with lines = 0 and word wrapping? UILabel has an intrinsic size where UITextView does not.

Comment: Does the UITextView need to be editable?

Comment: Thanks, I didn't really think about using a UILabel in that way but I agree that for what i"m trying to achieve that is a better way to do it.